# how can I make the sibling views response their gesture togegher?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
    
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 100, 200, 400)];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}
```

such as this case. If I touch the tableView and move down. And the tableview will scroll. But the scrollView will not move. How can I fix it to make the two sibling views response the gesture together?

Comment: Why do you want to embed a scrollable table view in a scroll view?